# .net process string values to class object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a weird requirement like I am receiving an input string value like below:

```
Id: 1 Caption: some caption Title: some title Grade: some grade Level: some level
```

The string content is from legacy db and it is hard to change as it impacts lot of area. I need to push these values to my class

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Caption { get; set; }
  public int Title { get; set; }
  public int Grade { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any .net tools that intelligently process such string or any logic that works out to process string to an object that fits in above class?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I too think so.

Comment: Is every field always present in the string ?

Comment: My magic eight ball says: You will split that string on the “:” characters to help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Nope. some fields might not present.

Comment: That is a messed up format. Without a proper delimiter how will you tell if one of the keywords is actually part of the data or a field identifier?

Comment: @jjxtra, I agree. There's the challenge. I thought of using delimiter initially, then later I realised it could not be achieved because of field identifier or data identification.

Comment: Are the field delimitators always in the same order ?

Comment: @TheGeneral, yes. they are in same order

Comment: will it be possible to split the word using two delimiters? I am trying something like below as my fields are limited
1. First replace fields like below .replace('Id:', '$Id:') and will do for all fields
2. This will help me to identify the value required for each field. So, if I can use some  regex or double delimiters that takes word starting from : and ending to: $
Can this achievable? or not sure any challenges  I could face.

Comment: If all the “field” identifiers are a “single” word without spaces… then splitting on ”:” is doable and would be the starting step. Each item in the split after item [0] will have one extra word at the end. Item[1] = “1 Caption” item[2] = “some caption Title”… item[5] = "some level"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving Regex a go.

Try this:

```
var source = "Id: 1 Caption: some caption Title: some title Grade: some grade Level: some level";
var regex = new Regex(@"^Id:\ (?'Id'(\d+))\ Caption:(|\ (?'Caption'(.*))) Title:(|\ (?'Title'(.*)))\ Grade:(|\ (?'Grade'(.*)))\ Level:(|\ (?'Level'(.*)))$");
var match = regex.Match(source);

var output = new
{
    Id = match.Groups["Id"].Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups["Id"].Value) : -1,
    Caption = match.Groups["Caption"].Success ? match.Groups["Caption"].Value : "",
    Title = match.Groups["Title"].Success ? match.Groups["Title"].Value : "",
    Grade = match.Groups["Grade"].Success ? match.Groups["Grade"].Value : "",
    Level = match.Groups["Level"].Success ? match.Groups["Level"].Value : "",
};
```

That gives me:

[image: output]

You haven't given great detail on the structure of the input, but that works with the one example you have provided.

Comment: This answer is short and simple! Thanks for the solution! This is fine. will it be possible to use the above regex for array content as string. for example, consider the input string as 
Id: 1 Caption: some caption Id: 2 Caption: caption two

Comment: @Viswa - Yes, that is possible. Try `new Regex(@"^Id:\ (?'Id'(\d+))(\ Caption:(|\ (?'Caption'(.*?))))+? Title:(|\ (?'Title'(.*)))\ Grade:(|\ (?'Grade'(.*)))\ Level:(|\ (?'Level'(.*)))$");` with `Captions = match.Groups["Caption"].Success ? match.Groups["Caption"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray() : new string[] { },`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this

**Given**

```
public static MyClass FunkyDeserialize(string input)
{
   var array = new[] {"Id:", "Caption:", "Title:", "Grade:", "Level:"};

   var lastIndex = -1;
   var start = -1;
   var result = new MyClass();

   void Fill(int index, int start, int finish)
   {
      switch (index)
      {
         case 0: result.Id = int.Parse(input.Substring(start, finish).Trim()); break;
         case 1: result.Caption = input.Substring(start, finish).Trim(); break;
         case 2: result.Title = input.Substring(start, finish).Trim(); break;
         case 3: result.Grade = input.Substring(start, finish).Trim(); break;
         case 4: result.Level = input.Substring(start, finish).Trim(); break;
      }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
      var index = input.IndexOf(array[i]);
      if(index < 0)  continue;

      if (lastIndex >= 0)
         Fill(lastIndex, start, index - start);

      start = index+ array[i].Length;
      lastIndex = i; 
   }

   if (lastIndex >= 0)
      Fill(lastIndex, start, input.Length - start);

   return result;
}
```

Or another way

```
public static MyClass FunkyDeserialize(string input)
{

   (string Id,Action<int,int> Action) lastItem = default;

   var start = -1;
   var result = new MyClass();

   var list = new List<(string Id,Action<int,int> Action)>()
   {
      ("Id:", (x,y) => result.Id = int.Parse(input.Substring(x, y).Trim())), 
      ("Caption:", (x,y) =>result.Caption = input.Substring(x, y).Trim()),
      ("Title:", (x,y) =>result.Title = input.Substring(x, y).Trim()),
      ("Grade:", (x,y) =>result.Grade = input.Substring(x, y).Trim()),
      ("Level:", (x,y) =>result.Level = input.Substring(x, y).Trim())
   };

   foreach (var item in list)
   {
      var index = input.IndexOf(item.Id);
      if(index < 0) continue;
      lastItem.Action?.Invoke(start, index - start);
      start = index + item.Id.Length;
      lastItem = item;
 
   }

   lastItem.Action?.Invoke(start, index - start);

   return result;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "Id: 1 Caption: some caption Title: some title Grade: some grade Level: some level";

var result = FunkyDeserialize(input);

Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
Console.WriteLine(result.Caption);
Console.WriteLine(result.Title);
Console.WriteLine(result.Grade);
Console.WriteLine(result.Level);
```

**Output**

```
1
some caption
some title
some grade
some level
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWJE2l)

<sub>***Note** : This is not intended to be a 100% bullet proof solution, there is little sanity checking and fault tolerance. However, should be enough to get you started.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Using a different approach, but one that is certainly NOT bullet proof but may work for you. There is a pattern there, if the field identifiers are “single” words without spaces. Splitting on “:”, will give you something like….

```
    [0] "Id”
    [1] " 1 Caption"
    [2] " some caption Title"
    [3] " some title Grade”
    [4] " some grade Level"
    [5] " some level"
```

Each item in the split after item [0] will have one extra word at the end. The last item[5] would obviously not have this extra word. The method `RemoveLastWord` does just that to remove that last word.

```
private MyClass ParseData(string dataString) {
  string[] splitArray = dataString.Split(':');
  if (splitArray.Length >= 6) {
    string id = RemoveLastWord(splitArray[1].Trim());
    string cap = RemoveLastWord(splitArray[2].Trim());
    string title = RemoveLastWord(splitArray[3].Trim());
    string grade = RemoveLastWord(splitArray[4].Trim());
    string level = splitArray[5].Trim();
    if (int.TryParse(id, out int idValue)) {
      return new MyClass { Id = idValue, Caption = cap, Title = title, Grade = grade, Level = level };
    }
    else {
      // id is not a valid int setting to -1
      return new MyClass { Id = -1, Caption = cap, Title = title, Grade = grade, Level = level };
    }
  }
  return null;
}

private string RemoveLastWord(string data) {
  int lastIndex = data.LastIndexOf(" ");
  if (lastIndex > 0) {
    return data.Substring(0, lastIndex);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Class used above

```
public class MyClass {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Caption { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Grade { get; set; }
  public string Level { get; set; }
}
```